# I have 100 points and using the distance function I wanted to look for the shortest path

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

radius = 200
rangeX = (0, 2500)
rangeY = (0, 2500)
qty = 100  


s = set()
for x in range(-radius, radius+1):
    for y in range(-radius, radius+1):
        if x*x + y*y <= radius*radius:
            s.add((x,y))

rp = []
excluded = set()

i = 0

while i<qty:
    x = random.randrange(*rangeX)
    y = random.randrange(*rangeY)
    if (x,y) in excluded: 
        continue

    rp.append((x,y))

    i += 1

    excluded.update((x+dx, y+dy) for (dx,dy) in s)
#This is to find 100 random points based on the range and the radius


import math

points = rp


paths = ((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0,2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1))

def dist(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0]-p1[0])**2 + (p2[1]p1[1])**2)

distances = []


for path in paths:
distances.append(dist(points[path[0]], points[path[1]]) +
                 dist(points[path[1]], points[path[2]]) +
                 dist(points[path[2]], points[path[3]]) +
                 dist(points[path[3]], points[path[0]]))


print(f"the shortest path is {min(distances):.2f} cm and the longest path is {max(distances):.2f} cm")
#this allows the points from the 100 random points function to passed it going through the equation
```

So far I have encountered a few problems, the time it took to run the 100 points code is long which makes the code inefficient, and I also need a way to let me know what route "all the points that make up the shortest path"  allows the distance to be the shortest instead of just showing me the shortest path.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What specifically is your question?  You seem to be asking multiple questions, which is not acceptable for SO.  Please edit your question to create a Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE).  see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

To spot where your code is slow, the easiest method is to add several `time1 = time.time()` and print the differences at the end `print("1->2:", time2-time1)`.
Doing that I saw that 99,999% of the time is spent in the `while i<qty` loop.
I removed the `excluded.update` line and the code ran instantly.
I do not understand your code (nor took the time to do it), but that line kills your efficiency. You are adding 400² new points, 100 times.
You should search for a clever way to not do this. If you don't know how, this would be a precise question to ask in another post (explaining what you are doing and why).

As for printing which path is the shortest and which is the longest, this is easy : for each path you calculate its length, so you end up with a `distances` containing 6 values, one for each path, in the same order. So we can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together :

```
print(*zip(distances, paths))
# (5937.1207124153025, (0, 1, 2, 3))
# (7675.498300727197, (0, 1, 3, 2))
# (5715.663112364403, (0, 2, 1, 3))
# (7675.498300727197, (0, 2, 3, 1))
# (5715.663112364404, (0, 3, 1, 2))
# (5937.1207124153025, (0, 3, 2, 1))
```

and rely on Python's tuple ordering to return what we want :

```
shortest_path_length, shortest_path = min(zip(distances, paths))
longest_path_length, longest_path = max(zip(distances, paths))
print(f"the shortest path is {shortest_path_length:.2f} cm : {shortest_path}")
print(f"the longest path is {longest_path_length:.2f} cm : {longest_path}")
# the shortest path is 5715.66 cm : (0, 2, 1, 3)
# the longest path is 7675.50 cm : (0, 2, 3, 1)
```

Tip : you can use [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) for runs to be reproducible. Just add `random.seed(42)` (or whichever number you prefer) before any call to a rendom function and you'll be set.